# Pivot multiple columns from row to column

Tags: python, pyspark, pivot, transpose

I have a PySpark dataframe which looks like this:

```
| id   | name   | policy     | payment_name | count |
|------|--------|------------|--------------|-------|
| 2    | two    | 0          | Hybrid       | 58    |
| 2    | two    | 1          | Hybrid       | 2     |
| 5    | five   | 1          | Excl         | 13    |
| 5    | five   | 0          | Excl         | 70    |
| 5    | five   | 0          | Agen         | 811   |
| 5    | five   | 1          | Agen         | 279   |
| 5    | five   | 1          | Hybrid       | 600   |
| 5    | five   | 0          | Hybrid       | 2819  |
```

I would like to make the combination of `policy` and `payment_name` become a column with the respective count (reducing down to one row per `id`).

Output would look like this:

```
| id | name | no_policy_hybrid | no_policy_excl | no_policy_agen | policy_hybrid | policy_excl | policy_agen |
|----|------|------------------|----------------|----------------|---------------|-------------|-------------|
| 2  | two  | 58               | 0              | 0              | 2             | 0           | 0           |
| 5  | five | 2819             | 70             | 811            | 600           | 13          | 279         |
```

In cases where there is no combination we can default it to 0 i.e. `id` 2 has no combination including `payment_name` Excl so it is set 0 on the example output.

Answer (score 1):

To pivot the table, you would first need a grouping column to combine the `policy` and the `payment_name`.

```
df = df.withColumn("groupingCol", udf("{}_{}".format)("policy", "payment_name"))
```

When you have that, you can group by the `id and` name` columns and pivot the grouping column.

```
df.groupBy("id", "name").pivot("groupingCol").agg(F.max("count"))
```

That should return the correct table columns.

```
+---+----+------+------+--------+------+------+--------+
| id|name|0_Agen|0_Excl|0_Hybrid|1_Agen|1_Excl|1_Hybrid|
+---+----+------+------+--------+------+------+--------+
|  5|five|   811|    70|    2819|   279|    13|     600|
|  2| two|  null|  null|      58|  null|  null|       2|
+---+----+------+------+--------+------+------+--------+
```

To get the same column names as in your example, you can start with changing the content of the policy column to `policy` and `no_policy` like this:

```
df = df.withColumn("policy", when(col("policy") == 1, "policy").otherwise("no_policy"))
```

This is how you would replace the missing values with `0`:

```
df.na.fill(0)
```

Comment: I seem to be getting an error with the initial grouping - `PicklingError: Could not serialize object: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__code__'`. Also `df2` is never created before it's use, should that be `df2 = df1.groupBy ...` ?

Comment: instead of the udf [concat_ws](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws) could be used which might result in a _slightly_ better performance

Comment: @stackq df2 was the result of the first statement, that would add a grouping column

Comment: @LasseSviland Gotcha. Still have problems creating the initial grouping. I'm using Spark `2.2.0` so maybe that's why. Is there an alternative way to achieve the same?

Comment: @stackq You can try with the method werner suggested, `df.select("name", "id", "count", F.concat_ws('_', "policy", "payment_name").alias("groupingCol")).groupBy("id", "name").pivot("groupingCol").agg(F.max("count"))`